# Track clearance with flex region cutout in Altium Designer

Tags: pcb-design, altium, clearance, design-rules

In Altium Designer, I created a simple rigid-flex board with the 4 layers in the rigid part (top, in1, in2, bottom) and 2 layers in the flexible part (in1, in2).

I set 5mm clearance on a top layer track by means of a simple rule. On the rigid board, the track doesn't have 5mm clearance with respect to the board outline (which is the correct behaviour), but it has 5mm clearance with respect to the split line that divides the rigid part from the flex part.

Said in other words: I can route the track up to the very board border, except when it is a rigid-flex border.

How do I remove the 5mm clearance with respect to the border between the rigid and the flex part?

[image: Clearance problem description]

The error I get is `Celarance contraint between track on TopLayer and PolyRegion on MultiLater`:
[image: Error message]

The net with the problem has `class1` class; I set a simple 5mm clearance rule on this class. All other rules are set to Altium defaults.

[image: Rule]

The only way I found to remove the clearance violation is to set the clearance matrix as in the picture below, but this is not accepable for a standard circuit:
[image: dirty solution]

EDIT: I updated the image to be more clear.

EDIT 2: I added more screenshots.

Comment: Not an expert in terms of rules in altium but would something using a keep-out region work?

Comment: @JorenVaes I would like to have the opposite: no clearance everywhere. I updated the image to be more clear.

Comment: Could you move the border of the flex region back 5mm???

Comment: @KyleB no, the board shape is a contraint. Moreover, the image I posted is just an example to reproduce the problem. The real board is much more complex, and to properly route it I need the traks to go up to the board cutout.

Comment: Can you create a violation? Then the violation notice will tell you which rule you're breaking. If that doesn't give you enough information to fix it, add a screenshot of the rules dialog highlighting that rule to your question.

Comment: Turn off the realtime rules checks.  Then you can do anything you want.  You do not have to clear all violations to make Gerbers.   Just ignore the violations for that area when you do a final rule check

Comment: @KyleB The autorouter will follow this rule, so I need it to work properly.

Comment: @ThePhoton thanks for the suggestions. I added information to the question.

Comment: Autorouted boards look like autorouted boards.  When you give up on getting a good result from it, go back to my last suggestion.